Visual Studio 2022: How do you edit a .NET Core solution (.sln) file text directly in the IDE?
Typically whenever I need to directly edit the text of my solution (.sln) files, I've had to use an external text editor like Notepad++.  Unlike with project (.csproj) files, the right-click menu in VS does not show an option to edit the solution file directly.
Is there a way to do this?  Or am I stuck with using a separate text editor?

@DaveS yes I am also able to browse to the .sln file in explorer and edit it in Notepad++ or any other text editor.  And there is rarely a need to edit it directly.  I just assumed that MS would provide a way to do this (for the sake of consistency).

I believe, you can edit the solution, very similar to the way you edit a proj file, once unloading the project.  But the kicker is it must be one of the new slnx files (xml solution file) not the previous sln.
I can check this when I get back to my windows machine, and will edit this post if necessary.
I do know, you can create a new solution (and specify it's saved as slnx) - then import your projects to it without to much issue.  I've done this quite a bit pushing forward VS version and wanting a clean solution file.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
